# Method Not Allowed: / (Django-Post Method)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-2.1

When I submit the form, it says "Method Not Allowed: /" in the console..

Something like that:
Method Not Allowed: /
[17/Mar/2019 18:31:18] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405

---

I'm using this on views.py file..

```
class UrlAccpt(View):

    template_name='phc/url_accpt.html'

    def get(self,request):
        urlx=''
        form = UrlForm(request.POST)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UrlForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                urlx= form.cleaned_data['EnterTheUrl']

        form = UrlForm(request.POST)

    response = TemplateResponse(request,self.template_name,{'form':form,'value':urlx})
    return response
```

---

and in forms.py file...I use this code

```
from django import forms


class UrlForm(forms.Form):

    EnterTheUrl=forms.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to class based views:

You need to specify post function in your class. Get function only triggered on GET method, not for POST request.

Add following function and move your post logic here...

```
def post:
   ...
```

Have a look [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views)

Answer (score 1):

Class based views do not work this way. You have to define a method for every http method type you want to cover (At least if you are simply inheriting from `View`) class. So define a method in your class based view for post like this and it will work

```
class UrlAccpt(View):

    template_name='phc/url_accpt.html'

    def get(self,request):
        urlx=''
        form = UrlForm()

   def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UrlForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            urlx= form.cleaned_data['EnterTheUrl']
```

You can read about it in **Supporting other HTTP methods** of [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods) doc

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help... Noob here